# I need too find an orthonormal basis for Range of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

$T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ is defined by $T(x,y,z)=(x+y,y+z,z-x)$

Then I need too find an orthonormal basis for Range of $T$

$T(1,0,0)=(1,0,-1),T(0,1,0)=(1,1,0),T(0,0,1)=(0,1,1)$ could any one help me the steps? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we see that the vectors are dependent (take the determinant of the matrix that has them as rows and you will get $0$). Note that $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$ are independent, so they form a basis. However, this is not an orthonormal basis. The use [Gram-Schmidt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process):

Let

$u_1=(1,1,0)$, and

$u_2=(0,1,1)-\frac{(1,1,0)\cdot(0,1,1)}{(1,1,0)\cdot(1,1,0)}(1,1,0)$ $=(0,1,1)-\frac{1}{2}(1,1,0)=(-1/2,1/2,1)$

This is an orthogonal basis. Divide each one by their norm to obtain an orthonormal basis.